# JSON Schema conditional statements, prevent duplicate properties across multiple schemas

Tags: jsonschema

I have a JSON Schema with 2 properties `catalogA` and `catalogB`.

I have 4 nested properties:

- `story1`
- `story2`
- `story3`
- `story4`

I need a condition to validate that any one `story` property can't be defined in both `catalogs` or else the schema fails.

I tried using `not` syntax, but it's not working the way I expect it to.

```json
{
  "catalogA": [
    {
      "story1": "xyz",
      "story2": "abc"
    }
  ],
  "catalogB": [
    {
      "story3": "ddd",
      "story4": "ccc"
    }
  ]
} // this is valid

{
  "catalogA": [
    {
      "story1": "xyz",
      "story2": "abc"
    }
  ],
  "catalogB": [
    {
      "story1": "xyz",
      "story3": "ddd",
      "story4": "ccc"
    }
  ]
} // this is invalid
```

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "catalogA": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "story1": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "story2": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "story3": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "story4": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "catalogB": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "story1": {
            "type": "string",
            "not": {}
          },
          "story2": {
            "type": "string",
            "not": {}
          },
          "story3": {
            "type": "string",
            "not": {}
          },
          "story4": {
            "type": "string",
            "not": {}
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `if, then` syntax for something like this...

- You need to `require` each property in the `if` statement to validate it.
- Then check if the property is defined with `"story1": true`. This is shorthand for checking if `story1` has a schema defined.
- if `story<N>` exists, the `then` constraint is applied which looks at the other catalog to determine if the same property exists, and then applies a constraint of `"story1": false` to constraint the second catalog from allowing the same property
- we combine multiple `if, then` conditional statements inside an `allOf` to ensure all constraints are applied to the catalogs.

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "catalogA": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "story1": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "story2": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "story3": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "story4": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "catalogB": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "story1": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "story2": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "story3": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "story4": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "allOf": [
    {
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "catalogA": {
            "items": {
              "required": ["story1"],
              "properties": {
                "story1": true
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "then": {
        "properties": {
          "catalogB": {
            "items": {
              "properties": {
                "story1": false
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "catalogA": {
            "items": {
              "required": ["story2"],
              "properties": {
                "story2": true
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "then": {
        "properties": {
          "catalogB": {
            "items": {
              "properties": {
                "story2": false
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "catalogA": {
            "items": {
              "required": ["story3"],
              "properties": {
                "story3": true
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "then": {
        "properties": {
          "catalogB": {
            "items": {
              "properties": {
                "story3": false
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "catalogA": {
            "items": {
              "required": ["story4"],
              "properties": {
                "story4": true
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "then": {
        "properties": {
          "catalogB": {
            "items": {
              "properties": {
                "story4": false
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```